# Custom attributes used in Magento getPrice function not accessible on checkout page

Tags: php, magento

I am writing a custom `getPrice` function in **Magento** (extending the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` class) to calculate the prices of products based on a number of custom product attributes (like product brand, rrp, size, etc).

When I am on a product page I can access all of these custom attributes using `$product->getData('attribute')` or `$product->getAttributeText('attribute')`, but when I add a product to the shopping basket and open the shopping basket these product attributes are no longer accessible. I can access a few attributes (like product name), but not all.

Does anyone know how to work around this, or some pointers for me to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $product->load() first. Otherwise, make sure $product is actually a Mage_Catalog_Model_Product and not a Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item.

Comment: Great, a $product->load() inside getFinalPrice solved the issue. Thank you very much!!

Comment: FWIW: you actually need a $product->load($product->getProductId()), otherwise you end up with a Gb's of warnings in your systems.log

Comment: Through 1.6, that was not the case. I can't say regarding later versions, although I remember it being a fairly common pattern in core code.